# How can I access all R.color colors or how can I add new one

Tags: android, colors, mpandroidchart

I'm using mpandroidchart.It want to R.color.color to set label colors.

When i want to set color by R.color.x , I see only three colors.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGFb6.png)

How can i add new color or How can i use all [these](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color) colors.

Comment: just Write on your View like TextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.) & after "." its will gives you all colors which you want to use ;)

Comment: add color xml file(res->values->color file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it under your values folder:

[image]

In here you can add new colors.

Answer (score 0):

you can create `values/colors.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="menu_background">#666666</color>
</resources>
```

And reference it through `@color\menu_background"`

Answer (score 0):

In android studio go to res->values->colors define a new color with hex code like the other three colors . like this :

```
<color name="my_custom_name">#E91E63</color>
```

you can get the hex code of color from the site like : https://www.materialui.co/colors

[image: In android studio go to res->values->colors]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all of the existing answers didn't understand your question correctly.

To use the colors in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color, you just need to reference them with

```
android.R.color.[COLOR NAME]
```

instead of

```
R.color.[COLOR NAME]
```

which will instead reference the values in your colors.xml file.

You can also just add an import statement to the start of your file as well

```
import android.R.color
```